# How to redirect http url to https for django application served by Apache

Tags: django, apache, https, httpd.conf

What I want to achieve is when I browse for *http://example.com:8080* it gets redirected to *https://example.com:8080*.

My web application is written in Django, and I have the following line in my settings:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

The httpd configuration for example.com looks like this:

```
LISTEN 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName example.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path_to_cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path_to_key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path_to_iterm.cer

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

  Alias /static /path_to_mysite/static
  <Directory /path_to_mysite/static>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /path_to_mysite_wsgi_dir>
      <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
      </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/path_to_mysite:/path_to_mysite_python_packages display-name=%{GROUP}
  WSGIProcessGroup mysite
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path_to_mysite_wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

with these configurations when I browse http://example.com, I will get the following error:

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

any thoughts?

Comment: You can't have both HTTP and HTTPS served from the one port. Port 8080 will only be able to accept HTTPS requests.

Comment: BTW, don't use ``python-path`` to point at your virtual environment site packages. Read https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html to see how to configure virtual environment correctly.

Comment: I'm delighted to have your comment under my post :)

I remember that I had always problems when I used `python-home` to point at my virtual environment, and setting `python-path` resolved the issues (unfortunately I don't remember what was the problem). But now because of your comment, I removed `python-path`, and used `python-home` instead and it seems everything is working fine! I have no clue why :D

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect traffic from 8080 to https:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName example.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then enable ssl on port 443, which is the default port for https requests:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path_to_cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path_to_key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path_to_iterm.cer

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

  Alias /static /path_to_mysite/static
  <Directory /path_to_mysite/static>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /path_to_mysite_wsgi_dir>
      <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
      </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/path_to_mysite:/path_to_mysite_python_packages display-name=%{GROUP}
  WSGIProcessGroup mysite
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path_to_mysite_wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My first intention was to use both http and https on port 8080. But as Graham pointed out it's not possible. So I cannot mark this as correct answer. But your answer helped a lot to resolve my problem. thank you.

Comment: Np, I thought I'd expand on his comment a bit, glad it helped.